# How to leave scikit-learn esimator result in dask distributed system?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, dask, distributed, dask-distributed

You can find a minimal-working example below (directly taken from dask-ml page, only change is made to the `Client()` to make it work in distributed system)

```
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client

import joblib
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Don't forget to start the dask scheduler and connect worker(s) to it.
client = Client('localhost:8786')             

digits = load_digits()

param_space = {
    'C': np.logspace(-6, 6, 13),
    'gamma': np.logspace(-8, 8, 17),
    'tol': np.logspace(-4, -1, 4),
    'class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
}

model = SVC(kernel='rbf')
search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_space, cv=3, n_iter=50, verbose=10)

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    search.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
```

But this returns the result to the local machine. This is not exactly my code. In my code
 I am using [scikit-learn tfidf vectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). After I use `fit_transform()`, it is returning the fitted and transformed data (in sparse format) to my local machine. How can I leave the results inside the distributed system (cluster of machines)?

PS: I just encountered this [from dask_ml.wrappers import ParallelPostFit](https://ml.dask.org/meta-estimators.html#parallel-prediction-and-transformation) Maybe this is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in front of my eyes and I couldn't see it for 3 days of searching. [ParallelPostFit](https://ml.dask.org/meta-estimators.html#parallel-prediction-and-transformation) is the answer. The only problem is that it doesn't support `fit_transform()` but `fit()` and `transform()` works and it returns a lazily evaluated dask array (that is what I was looking for). Be careful about this warning:

> Warning
>
> `ParallelPostFit` does not parallelize the training step. The underlying
>   estimator’s `.fit` method is called normally.